# Error in populating sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my Android application I created a database using sqlite browser and cpoied it into asset folder. then I created a table named EMPerson.
I need to add user defined data(user can insert details such as personName,date_of_birth,age,gender & bloodGrp) into this EMPerson table when the user click save button.

My DBHelper class is like this.

```
package my.easymedi.db;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import my.easymedi.entity.Person;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

/*Database attributes - the Android's default system path for your application database*/
private static final String pkg = "my.easymedi.controller";
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + pkg + "/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "EasyMediInfo.jpeg";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private final Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase; 

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(myContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("CREATE_DB", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream databaseInput = null;
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;     //path to copy the database
    OutputStream databaseOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);    //open the empty db as an output stream

    databaseInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int length = databaseInput.read(buffer);
    while(length > 0){  
        databaseOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        databaseOutput.flush();
    }
    databaseOutput.flush();
    databaseInput.close();
    databaseOutput.close();
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Toast.makeText(myContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Check_DB", e.getMessage());
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

public void openDatabase() {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
}

public void closeDatabase() {
    if(myDatabase != null){
        myDatabase.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean insertIntoDatabase(Person person) {

    String query = "INSERT INTO EMPerson (COLUMN_PERSON_NAME, COLUMN_DOB , COLUMN_AGE, COLUMN_GENDER, COLUMN_BLOODGRP) " 
                    + " VALUES ('" + person.getName() + "', '" + person.getDate_of_birth() + "', '" + person.getAge() + "', '" + person.getGender() + "', '" + person.getBloodGrp() + "')";
    try {
        myDatabase.execSQL(query);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

And this is my AddNewPerson class segment.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnSave:
        personName = etName.getText().toString();
        date_of_birth = tvDOB.getText().toString();
        age = tvAge.getText().toString();

        int selected_rb_ID = genderGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();   
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected_rb_ID);
        gender = rb.getText().toString();
        bloodGrp = spiBloodGrp.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(personName);
        person.setDate_of_birth(date_of_birth);
        person.setAge(age);
        person.setGender(gender);
        person.setBloodGrp(bloodGrp);
        //personArrayList.add(person);

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        dbHelper.createDataBase();
        dbHelper.openDatabase();
        //SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        boolean flag = dbHelper.insertIntoDatabase(person);
        //long affectedColumnId = sqliteDatabase.insert(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA, null, contentValues);
        if(flag){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Values inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        dbHelper.closeDatabase();
        break;
```

When I run the application log cat says 'no such table:EMPerson'

Can anyone plz explain what's wrong with these codes.

Thanx in advance

Comment: your database name really has a jpeg extension ?

Comment: Yes.My db is EasyMediInfo.jpeg

Comment: You must rename your database from "EasyMediInfo.jpeg" to "EasyMediInfo.db"

Comment: use proper file extensions

Comment: I have tried like that but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Change the **DB_NAME to EasyMediInfo.db in Assets**

B/coz the extension of Database file is **.db**

**private static String DB_NAME = "EasyMediInfo.db";**

Edited:-

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2) {
            DB_PATH = myContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir
                    + "/databases/";
        } else {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + myContext.getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/";
        }
}
```

Comment: thats nt necessary :).. the db may have or may not have an extension, just that he should not have the extension as jpeg

Comment: 10-15 06:23:04.820: E/SQLiteLog(11782): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 06:23:04.820: E/SQLiteLog(11782): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/data/data/my.easymedi.controller/databases/EasyMediInfo.db) - 
10-15 06:23:04.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(11782): Failed to open database '/data/data/my.easymedi.controller/databases/EasyMediInfo.db'.
10-15 06:23:04.861: E/SQLiteDatabase(11782): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Comment: @user2856933 you are using Emulator of which version?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems:

1. Change the extension of your database to ".db" from ".jpeg" (just a suggestion for good coding practice)
2. It seems you do not properly initialize "mydatabase" variable in your code:

The line:

```
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

should be calling this.openDatabase(...)

Similarly, when your database doesn't exist you copy the database but doesn't initialize mydatabase again (you should call openDatabase again)

Also, you can then modify the function openDatabase as

```
public boolean openDatabase() {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

    return myDatabase!= null ? true : false;

}
```

Comment: I've changed checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS); into checkDB = this.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);But it seems error